# Exception while executing integration tests in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-profiles, maven-resources-plugin

Getting following exception while executing integration tests using `mvn verify` against my webapp. The integration tests just loads the server url using HtmlUnit and checks for the status code 200. Not sure what I am missing here. It looks like the resource filtering is not working as expected here. Please guide.

## Error Log:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.study.jenkins.it.htmlunit.PageIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.951 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.study.jenkins.it.htmlunit.PageIT
testScenario(com.study.jenkins.it.htmlunit.PageIT)  Time elapsed: 0.949 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ${server.url}
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:585)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:482)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:431)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.URLCreator.toNormalUrl(URLCreator.java:36)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.URLCreator$URLCreatorStandard.toUrlUnsafeClassic(URLCreator.java:82)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlUnsafe(UrlUtils.java:195)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
        at com.study.jenkins.it.htmlunit.PageIT.testScenario(PageIT.java:12)

Running com.study.jenkins.it.selenium.PageIT
```

## pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <dev.tc.base.url>http://dev-server.com</dev.tc.base.url>
    <tst.tc.base.url>http://tst-server.com</tst.tc.base.url>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <server.url>${dev.tc.base.url}/cicd-demo/</server.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>tst</id>
        <properties>
            <server.url>${tst.tc.base.url}/cicd-demo/</server.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

## src/test/resources/url.properties

```
server.url=${server.url}
```

Comment: Not a Maven expert. But from the look of the stack trace, it is not able to replace the ${server.url} value with your http url to dev or tst server.

Comment: why do you expect maven to just replace keys in properties file to its value from system param

Comment: I am trying to run integration tests on different env's. One thing worth mentioning is that I when I move both the url.properties and xpath.properties to src/main/resources and udpate the element to <directory>src/main/resources</directory> things start working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the filtering problem with test resources.

Replaced

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

with

```
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```